# What does it mean in terms of C#?

Tags: c#, .net, decompiler, dotpeek

I found the following compiler-generated code using DotPeek analyzing one of .NET assemblies:

```
[UnsafeValueType, NativeCppClass]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 16)]
internal struct DWriteTextAnalysisNode<MS::Internal::Text::TextInterface::Native::IDWriteNumberSubstitution *>
{
}
```

I am wondering what it means? How to rewrite this in C#? Especially this part:

```
<MS::Internal::Text::TextInterface::Native::IDWriteNumberSubstitution *>
```

Comment: IDWriteNumberSubstitution us a COM interface. The rest of the name sounds like just an artificial qualifier

Comment: This code is already in c#

Comment: What does angle brackets and star sign mean here?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov How could I write and compile similar using mocks?

Comment: You cannot mock it (it is COM, and it is unsafe). To mock you should write wrapper class and mock wrapper

Comment: The star denotes a pointer, and angle brackets typically surround type parameters.  You might want to read up on both concepts before you get in too much further.  You're about a quarter of a step away from all the C++ stuff that C# tries to protect you from.

Comment: @cHao Why would someone like to have struct SomeStruct<SomeType *>? Why not SomeStruct<T>?

Comment: @QuéPadre: C++ templates aren't quite the same as C# generics.  Because using different parameters can radically change the interpretation of the template, C++ basically has to create a new class for each combination of template name and type parameters it sees used.

Comment: @cHao Exactly! Now i got it! .NET makes a slob out of me =)

Comment: @cHao Still didn't get something... Why would someone need to define C++ struct in C# code?

Comment: @QuéPadre: Because it's not C# code.  You're not seeing the code as they wrote it; you're seeing it as DotPeek's C#-scented decompiler interpreted it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You found this back in PresentationCore.dll.  You are looking at code that was written in C++/CLI, not C#.  It is one of the three major Microsoft .NET languages, beyond C# and VB.NET.  Definitely the ugly step daughter, C++/CLI reason for being is its unparalleled ability to interop with native code written in C or C++.

Which gets lots of use in PresentationCore, System.Data as well, it contains heavy native code interop to take advantage of existing Microsoft apis.  In this case it is [DirectWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368038%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), a text rendering api.  It is a pretty complex native api that's well beyond the ability of standard pinvoke to interop with.  C++/CLI supports using the native COM-style interfaces directly.

One aspect of C++/CLI is that the native C++ interfaces and classes can bleed into the assembly metadata.  It is a bit of a flaw, it doesn't have a great way to suppress visibility of the native types.  Only the opposite, making them visible with `#pragma make_public`.  The C++/CLI compiler must generate a metadata definition for the type that's compatible with assembly metadata.  Since these are native types under the hood, the closest reasonable match is a *value type*.   It is entirely opaque, you don't see the members of the type.  Just a blob, pretty similar to fixed size buffer types in C#.

So this is just an artifact.  There's no sensible way to do the same thing in C#, nor is there a reason to.